# Did Benjamin know what happen to Yosef in real time?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, agada-stories-legends

It is mentioned in the sources that Benjamin named his sons after what Joseph went through when he was separated from his family: And the sons of Benjamin, Bela and Becher and Ashbel, Gera and Naaman, Ahi and Rosh; Mofis and Beaches, Rose (Genesis 46:21). After all, they were born gradually, during Joseph's absence and while he was in Egypt. And if so, it appears that Benjamin knew what was done and happened to Yosef and the question is how did he know? And if he knew, why didn't he tell his family and go down to Egypt to save Yosef?